# How to get access public_ftp and server files in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, ftp

I have store images in `public_ftp`. Now how can i access `public_ftp` files. I have link and also `username` and `password`.But how can i use `public_ftp` link in `server mappath`.

```
   string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~\\screenshots\\" +eventID));
            IEnumerable<string> filess = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            // Get all the files in the sourceDir
            foreach (string name in myList)
            {

                string fname = name;
                path = Server.MapPath("~\\screenshots\\" +eventID+"\\" + fname);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                {
                    var attachment = new System.Web.Mail.MailAttachment(path);
                    myMail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                }

            }
```

How can i use ftp link in `Server.MapPath('FTP LINK')` Also let me know how can i access server files if someone store files on server and he provide me credentials and i want to access images and use in application. I don't want to store images in my hosting server due to privacy.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Server.MapPath to access to an FTP, you need to use specific Library to work with FTP.
.NET have a class to make this, FTPWebRequest

http://www.vcskicks.com/download-file-ftp.php